# Make line chart with multiple series and error bars

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm hoping to create a line graph which shows the changes to flowering and fruiting times (phenophases) from year to year. For each phenophase I'd like to plot the average Day of Year and, if possible, show the min and max for each year as an error bar. I've filtered down all the data I need in a few data frames, grouped it all in a sensible way, but I can't figure out how to get it all to plot. Here's a screen grab of where I'm at: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVFWA.jpg)

All the examples I've found adding error bars have been based on formulas or other equal amounts over/under, but in my case the max/min will be different so I'm not sure how to integrate that. Possible just create a list of each column's data and feed that to plot? I'm playing with that now but not getting far.

Also, if anyone has general suggestions as to better ways to present this data I'm all ears. I've looked into Gantt plots but didn't get far with them, as this seems a bit more straight-forward just using matplotlib. I'm happy to put some demo data or the rest of my notebook up if anyone thinks that would help.

Edit: Here's some sample data and the code from my notebook: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/plytheman/cea0fef52b570c4e4c97c9d35c9bdbb9)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
%matplotlib inline
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 40)
tick_spacing = 1

dfClean = df[['Site_Cluster', 'Species', 'Phenophase_Name', 
              'Phenophase_Status', 'Observation_Year', 'Day_of_Year']]
dfClean = dfClean[dfClean.Phenophase_Status == 1]

PhenoNames = ['Open flowers', 'Ripe fruits']
dfLakes = dfClean[(dfClean.Phenophase_Name.isin(PhenoNames)) 
                  & (dfClean.Site_Cluster == 'Lakes')
                 & (dfClean.Species == 'lapponica')]
dfLakesGrouped = dfLakes.groupby(['Observation_Year', 'Phenophase_Name'])
dfLakesReady = dfLakesGrouped.Day_of_Year.agg([np.min, np.mean, np.max]).round(0)
dfLakesReady = dfLakesReady.unstack()

print(dfLakesReady['mean'].plot())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So sample data and your existing code reproducing your problem are more than welcome. And don't post pictures of code/error messages, post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another answer:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, date_range, Timedelta
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rng = date_range(start='2015-01-01', periods=5, freq='24H')
df = DataFrame({'y':np.random.normal(size=len(rng))}, index=rng)
y1 = df['y']
y2 = (y1*3)
sd1 = (y1*2)
sd2 = (y1*2)

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)

_ = y1.plot(yerr=sd1, ax=ax1)
_ = y2.plot(yerr=sd2, ax=ax2)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think this does it! [Here's where I'm at](https://gist.github.com/plytheman/79587ba64b85469a4fd5661a99cd998b#file-gistfile1-txt) (as I don't think I can post a block of code in a comment?) And the result [here](https://imgur.com/a/bJQZlD4). Thanks for setting me on the right path!